# Build failed with ionic android

Tags: android, cordova, ant, ionic-framework

Maybe it can help you on build error with ionic/cordova error with android platform on windows

After install ant/ionic with :

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools
```

start a new projet : ionic start hello blank ->ok
ionic platform add android -> ok
ionic build android - Error:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\SDK\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:954: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\SDK\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:971: null returned: -1073741819

Total time: 2 seconds

D:\PROD\myapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,D:\PROD\myapp\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: D:\PROD\myapp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
```

Paths are OK and if I start a new cordova projet (not ionic) build is a success.

If I check problem on c:\android-sdk\build.xml and I add

```
<echo>aapt:  ${aapt}</echo>
```

I can see aapt.exe path is on android-21 (target is android-19)

> For me, problem is I have two android sdk : android 19 and android 21. If I use CLI on windows, ionic/cordova choose android-21\aapt.exe by default and no android-19\aapt.exe
>
> I tried to force Path with android version : %ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools\19.0.0 with no success.
>
> To resolve this problem I changed paths to force on aapt executable path to point on android 19: 
>   File c:\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml :

```
<aapt executable="C:\android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.0\aapt.exe" ...
</aapt>
```

This is not the best way, but I have not found another.

Answer (score 1):

**Instruction 1:**

After adding your **ANDROID_HOME**, make sure you do the below:

1. Restart your System or **run source ~/.bash_profile**
2. Remove Android platform from your project **ionic cordova platform rm android** or **ionic platform rm android**
3. Add Android platform **ionic cordova platform add android**
4. Then **ionic cordova run android** or **ionic run android**

**Instruction 2:** 
To set your **ANDROID_HOME** and **JAVA_HOME**, follow the below steps:

1. Run command **open ~/.bash_profile**
2. Paste the below in the file that opens on your Text editor

**export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools**

3. Save  -  "**Command S**" or "**Ctrl S**"
4. Then Follow the "Instruction 1:" above

**NOTE: Make sure you have **24.4.1_1** SDK**

Hope this helps.